# removing visarg in sanskrit sandhi

Tags: sanskrit, sandhi

I have understood this example of visarg sandhi.

```
पुनः + रमते = पुना रमते
```

As per this page:
https://knowledgegallery.in/visarg-sandhi-in-sanskrit/

```
‘रो रि’। यदि विसर्ग (:) से पहले स्वर हो और उसके (विसर्ग के) बाद र् आए, तो विसर्ग का लोप हो जाता है। लोप करने पर विसर्ग से पूर्व स्वर को दीर्घ हो जाता है
```

As per this logic, is the folloing correct?

```
रामः + रमते =  रामा रमते
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about the grammar of a specific language are generally considered off-topic here unless coming from a linguistic perspective (linguistics being the scientific study of language, and so not just covering all questions about languages)

Comment: There is no rule in Sanskrit removing visarga. There is a rule removing *r* before *r*.

Comment: @user6726 While it doesn’t apply to the short-vowel examples given in the question here, there certainly is a rule in Sanskrit removing visarga: in _-āḥ_ + voiced consonant, visarga disappears regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is wrong. The correct sandhi and rules are as follows:

रामः + रमते = रामस् + रमते = **रामो रमते**

This is a basic rule in which word-final `अस्` becomes `ओ` before semivowels. This does ***NOT*** apply to cases where visarga is from a word-final `अर्` as in पुनः (पुनर्). For word-final `अर्` the following rule applies:

पुनः + रमते = पुनर् + रमते = **पुना रमते**

In this case, the visarga is actually a `र्` in pausa. The rule here is that if the next word starts with र् (or ढ्), then the word-final `र्` is deleted and there is vowel lengthening of preceding अ. Same applies to उर् and इर्.

As a side note, if Sanskrit did have this rule for `अस्`, the sandhi would completely change the meaning of the noun. Instead of the boy रामः enjoying himself, it would now be the girl रामा enjoying herself. When changed to रामो, it is clear it is still a boy रामः in sandhi and sandhi doesn't change the meaning of the sentence.

**Edit** - Adding Pānini's sutras for this (*pratyāhāras* are in boldface):

Due to रो रि followed by ढ्रलोपे पूर्वस्य दीर्घोऽणः

- रो रि implies अव्ययान्त अ + विसर्ग + र् -> विसर्गलोप
- ढ्रलोपे पूर्वस्य दीर्घोऽणः immediately follows रो रि and implies विसर्गलोप converts the previous vowel to *dīrgha*

Therefore,
पुनः + रमते = पुन + रमते -> पुना रमते

Because पुनः is *avyaya* (indeclinable) ending in a + visarga, so it follows this rule.

For all other words ending in a + visarga, such as रामः, the following applies.

(अतो रोरप्लुतादप्लुते) हशि च followed by आद्गुणः

- हशि च implies अ + विसर्ग + **हश्** -> उ
- आद्गुणः implies अ + उ -> ओ

रामः + रमते = राम + उ + रमते -> रामो रमते

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldboOBqeDKQ

Comment: This is a basic rule in which word-final अस् becomes ओ before semivowels.  Is there a "panini" rule for that?

Comment: @shantanuo see my edit

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. I asked because this telegram bot is suggesting both options. रामो रमते and रामा रमते https://t.me/SanskritOneBot